# Is there a maximum file size limit on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs, rclone, git-annex

My goal was to use a GitHub repo as a private server for updating an app I made (don't want to publish on a market, I want it remains private).

However, the problem started because I had a large file that was above the GitHub file size limit, so I found GitLFS which could handle a file of up to 1GB and it worked (I could easily upload and download the file).

After that, the issue was the limited bandwidth/storage per month which is 1GB [(if I download a 500MB file from GitLFS on two different devices I end the bandwidth)](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage), so I decided not to use GitLFS and now I'm asking if there are any alternative solutions, especially GitLab.

I want to know if GitLab can be good for this because I didn't find any file size limit.
I also saw a little about [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) and [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) and I am wondering if I can combine one of these two with GitLab.

Comment: `any alternative solutions` Run your own server. You'll have as much space as you will be able to pay for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitLab Free](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/):

> 5GB storage
>
> 10GB transfer per month

> Storage limits are applied at the top-level namespace. All storage consumed by projects within a namespace is counted, including the git repositories, LFS, package registries, and artifacts.

[And then](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/usage_quotas.html):

> Purchase additional storage units at $60/year for 10GB of storage.

I could not find a single-file limit.

Hosted storage costs money. Free tiers are just to lure you into their ecosystem. Host your own LFS server if you think that's cheaper.

Comment: thank you. I know storage costs, it's a strange situation because right now I don't need too much or too little storage/bandwidth. Btw I will use gitlab in the end.